# How to avoid Database Query for validating user action

Tags: java

Following are the two approaches to validate the current action

1. Save user details on login in the user session. For every action after login, check whether user has roles and permissions every time. DB needs to be queried since an administrator can change the privilege of the user any time. Query the roles and permissions of the current user and verify the operation every time.
2. Save user details on login in the user session. For every action after login, check just the roles/permission associated with the session. DB doesn't needs to be queried. However if Administrator or any user changes the permission of the current user from different country invalidate the current user session which should be stored somewhere.

Which of the above would be the best approach on the above ? How to achieve it

Many applications hit the DB for every action.

Some application invalidate the session...

Any reference or code snippet for the above two would be helpful

Not sure whether any other approach is available other than the two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could employ a hybrid approach: cache roles+permissions in user session for N minutes, then invalidate cache and reload them from the database. Thus, user permissions would be incorrect for no longer than N minutes.

Another approach is to store last update date+time per role in memory and in user session. When an administrator updates role permissions, you set 'update date+time' for this role to 'now'. Also, for each user action, you first check whether 'load date+time' for their role stored in their session is older than that global update date+time stored in memory. If it is older, then you need to reload role and its permissions from database.

This will only work well if

1. You only have one application instance (no distribution), or you can share that data a lot faster than access the database (some kind of a distributed cache?)
2. Permissions are changed by administrator via the same application
3. Your security model is not too complex

Imagine that you have an object `roleUpdateTimes` that contains a map from a role to its last update date+time (or `null` if the role was not updated since last restart).

When a role is updates by an administrator, the following is done:

```
roleUpdateTimes.updated(roleName);
```

where `updated()` method just puts the current date to the map:

```
public void updated(String roleName) {
    map.put(roleName, new Date());
}
```

`map` may be a `ConcurrentHashMap` here, so that we have a correct behavior knowing that the map will be accessed by different threads.

For the user, you could have the following in a `Filter`:

```
Date roleDate = getRoleDateFromSession(session);
String roleName = getRoleNameFromSession(session);
if (roleUpdateTimes.roleIsStale(roleName, roleDate)) {
    ... reload role permissions from database and save them to session
    saveRoleDateToSession(session, new Date());
}
```

And

```
public void roleIsStale(String roleName, Date snapshotDate) {
    Date updateDate = map.get(roleName)) {
    if (updateDate == null) {
        // role was not changed by admin, it's not stale
        return false;
    }
    return updateDate.after(snapshotDate);
}
```

Also you might need to load `map` on startup: just put `new Date()` for every known role.

Comment: I am fine with the second approach update date+time. Can u please elaborate as i couldn't understand better..thanks for your valuable time

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind details